# Catching a Dependency Issue in an Apache HBase Project in Java

Tags: java, hbase, dependency-management

While I am diving today in the source code of [apache hbase project](https://github.com/apache/hbase/), I encountered some difficulties to follow up with a dependency to access its source code: `HBase Unsafe`, which is mentioned in the following file and some other files as:

> [`import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.unsafe.HBasePlatformDependent;`](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/ByteBufferUtils.java#L34)

I tried to look for this package: `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.unsafe`, but nothing showed up.

Also, I checked the dependencies with maven, pom.xml and searched it with my IDE, and also searched online, but nothing seems to give any direct link to it.

Its auto-generated? if yes how can I know how its done? if not, is there a tool or method to follow the links for this dependency in the future?

I expect to access the source code of this class: `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.unsafe`. and the method to re-do this process in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the source code, of this dependency:

> `import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.unsafe.HBasePlatformDependent;`

which is included from another mirror repository related the HBASE project with the name of the name of [https://github.com/apache/hbase-thirdparty](https://github.com/apache/hbase-thirdparty/)
and the class I was searching for is located under:

> `hbase-unsafe/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/unsafe/HBasePlatformDependent.java`

The process I followed to find out where the package is located is to search for any related project to the HBASE project, as turned out this class is used in many other packages and I succeeded finally to get access to a common code-base which in my case is `hbase-thirdparty`. Maybe it's a not the best method but it worked.